# Integrating hat functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I am trying to integrate a hat function for a project that I am doing and have found a method to do so but I find it sloppy. Currently I have the basis function

```
\[Psi][z_] := z - Subscript[Z, i]/ \[CapitalDelta]z + 1;
```

which I am trying to integrate from $z_{i-1}$ to $z_{i+1}$. I break the basis function up into two pieces and integrate the left side from $z_{i-1}$ to  $z_{i}$ and then the right side from $z_i$ to $z_{i+1}$. My first question is, is there a way to integrate piecewise functions? The second question I have is, is there a way to  set global assumptions like $z_{i-1} < z_i < z_{i+1}$, $z_i - z_{i-1} = \Delta z$ , etc?

**Edit**: This is the piece wise function taken directly from my code I am trying to integrate

```
\[Psi][z_, c_] :=  Piecewise[{{(z - c)/\[CapitalDelta]z + 1, 
 z <= c}, {-(z - c)/\[CapitalDelta]z + 1, z > c}}];
```

where $c$ is the center of the hat function. Here is my attempt to integrate the piece wise function

```
 FullSimplify[
 Integrate[\[Psi][z, Subscript[Z, i]], {z, Subscript[Z, i - 1], 
   Subscript[Z, i + 1]}], 
 Assumptions -> {-(Subscript[Z, i + 1] - Subscript[Z, 
       i ]) == -\[CapitalDelta]z, 
   Subscript[Z, i + 1] - Subscript[Z, 
     i ] == \[CapitalDelta]z, -(Subscript[Z, i] - Subscript[Z, 
       i - 1 ]) == -\[CapitalDelta]z, 
   Subscript[Z, i] - Subscript[Z, i - 1 ] == \[CapitalDelta]z}]
```

I do not get a usable answer. Am I doing something wrong (ie can one integrate a piece wise function)?

Comment: Why are using using global variables not good? I would never know the value of $Z_i$ in the scope of this project and $\Delta z$ can have many values so I don't really see how else I could express the function.

Comment: Have you looked at `Piecewise`? Did you know that `Integrate` can take symbolic values (such as `Subscript[z,i-1]`) in its integration limits?

Comment: @Nasser: Thanks for the tip! However, the value of $Z_i$ is some undeclared constant in my code, as are $Z_{i+1}$, $Z_{i-1}$.

Comment: @Xerxes: Yes I have. See the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: *Mathematica* has no problem integrating piecewise or hat functions.

Your notation seems to me to be needlessly complex. Why bother to define $Z_i$ when it's just $Z_0+i\Delta z$? Isn't your $\psi$ just `1-Abs[z-c]/Δz`? However, I'll try to adhere to the spirit of your notation. Here's some code that works for me:

```
Zdefs = {Subscript[Z, i] - Subscript[Z, i - 1] == Δz, 
   Subscript[Z, i + 1] - Subscript[Z, i] == Δz};
Integrate[ψ[z, Subscript[Z, i]],
   {z, Subscript[Z, i - 1], Subscript[Z, i + 1]} /. 
  Solve[Zdefs, {Subscript[Z, i + 1], Subscript[Z, i - 1]}][[1]], 
 Assumptions -> Δz > 0 && 
   Subscript[Z, i] ∈ Reals]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Xerxes! I was emulating the notation used in our analytical solution. It makes the code easier to compare to our results. I do have a few questions for you though. I don't understand why you use this : /. 
  Solve[Zdefs, {Subscript[Z, i + 1], Subscript[Z, i - 1]}][[1]] ? Also what does this [[1]] mean? Sorry if these questions are especially basic.

Comment: Since your definitions of $Z_{i\pm 1}$ can be reduced to functions of $Z_i$ and $\Delta z$, `Solve` will do that for us. The `[[1]]` tells Mathematica to take the first (and only) solution to those equations. You don't have to do that; you can instead add `Subscript[Z, i - 1] < Subscript[Z, i] < Subscript[Z, i + 1]` to your `Assumptions`. But then you'll have to make the substitution later anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your integral would have worked too, if you had added assumptions that all variables are real:

```
(* New assumptions so Integrate can do its work *)
Assuming[{z \[Element] Reals, 
  c \[Element] Reals, \[CapitalDelta]z \[Element] Reals, 
  Subscript[Z, i - 1] \[Element] Reals, 
  Subscript[Z, i + 1] \[Element] Reals},

 (* The rest is just copied from the question *)
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[\[Psi][z, Subscript[Z, i]], {z, Subscript[Z, i - 1], 
   Subscript[Z, i + 1]}], 
 Assumptions -> {-(Subscript[Z, i + 1] - Subscript[Z, 
       i ]) == -\[CapitalDelta]z, 
   Subscript[Z, i + 1] - Subscript[Z, 
     i ] == \[CapitalDelta]z, -(Subscript[Z, i] - Subscript[Z, 
       i - 1 ]) == -\[CapitalDelta]z, 
   Subscript[Z, i] - Subscript[Z, i - 1 ] == \[CapitalDelta]z}]]
```

Result:

$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{3 \left(Z_i-Z_{i+1}\right){}^2}{\text{$\Delta $z}} & Z_i>Z_{i+1} \\
 \frac{\left(Z_i-Z_{i+1}\right){}^2}{\text{$\Delta $z}} & Z_i<Z_{i+1} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$