# Poor performance when evaluating double integral of hat functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, symbolic

I am trying to evaluate a double integral but am having performance issues.

**First a bit of math**

I am using a Galerkin like scheme to discretize operators in an equation I am working with. The problem I am trying to solve is this:

I start with hat functions in x and y,

$
\Psi_j(z) \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       \frac{1}{\Delta z}(z-z_{j-1}) & , z < z_j\\
       -\frac{1}{\Delta z}(z-z_{j-1}) & , z >z_j \\
       0 & , \left\vert z - z_j \right\vert > \Delta z \\
     \end{array}
   \right. ,
$

$
\Psi_i(y) \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       \frac{1}{\Delta y}(y-y_{i-1}) & , y < y_i\\
       -\frac{1}{\Delta y}(y-y_{i-1}) & , y >y_i \\
       0 & , \left\vert y - y_i \right\vert > \Delta y \\
     \end{array}
   \right. .
$

where $i$ and $j$ correspond to a node on our grid. I then define an arbitrary function and the variable of interest (pressure in my case) as,

$
\Theta(y,z) \cong \sum\limits_i \sum\limits_j \Theta_{ij} \Psi_i(y)\Psi_j(z) ,
$

$
p(y,z) \cong \sum\limits_i \sum\limits_j p_{ij} \Psi_i(y)\Psi_j(z) .
$

The arbitrary function corresponds to the coefficient of the operator we are approximating. The integral I am trying to solve is,

$
\Theta p |_{z = z_i} \cong \frac{\int \int \Psi_i \Psi_j \Theta p dz dy}{\int \int \Psi_i \Psi_j dz dy}
$

**Now the Code**

I am building off of what I [had done earlier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19521/integrating-hat-functions).

Here are the piecewise functions:

```
ψzt[z_, c_] := Piecewise[{{(z - c)/Δz + 1, z <= c}, 
                          {-(z - c)/Δz + 1, z > c}}];
ψz[z_, c_] := Piecewise[{ {ψzt[z, c], ψzt[z, c] > 0}, 
                          {0, ψzt[z, c] <= 0}}];
ψyt[y_, c_] := Piecewise[{{(y - c)/Δy + 1, y <= c}, 
                          {-(y - c)/Δy + 1, y > c}}];
ψy[y_, c_] := Piecewise[{ {ψyt[y, c], ψyt[y, c] > 0}, 
                          {0, ψyt[y, c] <= 0}}];
```

Here are the functions I have defined (I just expand the double sum):

```
θ [y_, z_] := 
Subscript[θ, i - 1, j - 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i - 1]] ψz[z,Subscript[Z, i - 1]] +               
Subscript[θ, i - 1,j] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i - 1]] +  
Subscript[θ, i - 1,j + 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i + 1]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i - 1]] +  
Subscript[θ, i,j - 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i - 1]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z,i]] +
Subscript[θ, i,j] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i]] + 
Subscript[θ, i, j + 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i + 1]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z,i]] +  
Subscript[θ, i + 1,j - 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i + 1]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i - 1]] +  
Subscript[θ, i + 1,j] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i + 1]] + 
Subscript[θ, i + 1,j + 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i + 1]] ψz[z,Subscript[Z,i + 1]]; 


μ[y_, z_] := 
Subscript[μ, i - 1, j - 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i - 1]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i - 1]] +  
Subscript[μ, i - 1, j] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i - 1]] + 
Subscript[μ, i - 1,j + 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i + 1]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z,i - 1]] +  
Subscript[μ, i,j - 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i - 1]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i]] +
Subscript[μ, i, j] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i]] +
Subscript[μ, i, j + 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i + 1]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i]] +
Subscript[μ, i + 1, j - 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i + 1]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z,i - 1]] + 
Subscript[μ, i + 1,j] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i + 1]] + 
Subscript[μ, i + 1,j + 1] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i + 1]] ψz[z, Subscript[Z,i + 1]];
```

Note: We use $\mu$ to represent $p$.

Here are the assumptions I make:

```
BasisAssumY = {Δy > 0, Subscript[Y, i] ∈ Reals,
y ∈ Reals, Δy ∈ Reals, 
Subscript[Y, i - 1] ∈ Reals, 
Subscript[Y, i + 1] ∈ Reals, 
Subscript[Y, i - 1] < Subscript[Y, i] < Subscript[Y, i + 1], 
Subscript[Y, i + 1] - Subscript[Y, i ] == Δy, 
Subscript[Y, i] - Subscript[Y, i - 1 ] == Δy, 
Subscript[Y, i ] - Subscript[Y, i + 1] == -ΔY};
```

The same assumptions are made in the z direction.

```
BasisRulesAll = {Subscript[Z, i + 1] - Subscript[Z, 
i ] -> Δz, 
Subscript[Z, i] - Subscript[Z, i - 1 ] -> Δz, 
Subscript[Z, i ] - Subscript[Z, i + 1] -> -Δz, 
Subscript[Y, i + 1] - Subscript[Y, i ] -> Δy, 
Subscript[Y, i] - Subscript[Y, i - 1 ] -> Δy, 
Subscript[Y, i ] - Subscript[Y, i + 1] -> -Δy};
```

Here is my integrating procedure:

```
Simplify[Integrate[
Integrate[ψz[z, Subscript[Z, i]]  θ [y, z] μ [y, 
    z], {z, Subscript[Z, i - 1], Subscript[Z, i + 1]}, 
  Assumptions -> BasisAssumZ] ψy[y, Subscript[Y, i]], {y, 
 Subscript[Y, i - 1], Subscript[Y, i + 1]}, 
Assumptions -> 
 BasisAssumY]/(Δz Δy)] //. \BasisRulesAll
```

This will run for hours without returning a result. In contrast, I have done a similar calculation in 1D (get the notebook [here](http://ilmfinitycom.ipage.com/Shared/1DExample.nb)) that takes about 10 seconds.

I did manage to get the integral to evaluate but I had to remove all $y$ terms from the $x$ integral (I grouped together like terms and factored). After doing that, the integral took about 10 seconds to be evaluated, but it was very messy and I cannot be sure that human error was not introduced. It would be simpler if the method above worked in a reasonable amount of time.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could improve the performance of the double integration?

Comment: Do you mean that the `θ[y, z]` and `μ[y, z]` appearing at the end of the code take the form of your `ϕ[y, z]` by saying "The p term takes the same form but is represented by μ"? Also, are you aware that `Integrate` has a syntax for multiple integral e.g. `Integrate[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}]`?

Comment: I added the function for $\mu$ in. I accidentally put the $\phi$ function instead of our $\theta$ function. I did know that you could integrate using a single command but it does not speed things up.

Comment: Based on the context of your question, I think there's a typo in the last element of your `BasisAssumY ` i.e. the `ΔY` should be `Δy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial I managed to speed your integration up. The main idea for the optimization is to simplify the symbolic expression as much as possible before throw it in to `Integrate`. Also, your code can be conciser for many parts of it, I'll mention a few of them in the following part.

This is the expression waiting for simplification:

```
exp = ψy[y, Y[i]] ψz[z, Z[i]] θ[y, z] μ[y, z]
```

Notice that I've changed all of your `Subscript[a_, b__]` in to something like `a[b]` for `Subscript` in some case can be quite troublesome so it's better not to use it.

First, since your `θ[y, z]` and `μ[y, z]` have the same form and they're in fact just be used as replacing rule, you don't need to define them as 2 separate functions, just use a rule:

```
functionrule = ϕ_[y, z] -> 
       ϕ[i - 1, j - 1] ψy[y, Y[i - 1]] ψz[z, Z[i - 1]] + 
       ϕ[i - 1, j] ψy[y, Y[i]] ψz[z, Z[i - 1]] + 
       ϕ[i - 1, j + 1] ψy[y, Y[i + 1]] ψz[z, Z[i - 1]] + 
       ϕ[i, j - 1] ψy[y, Y[i - 1]] ψz[z, Z[i]] + 
       ϕ[i, j] ψy[y, Y[i]] ψz[z, Z[i]] +
       ϕ[i, j + 1] ψy[y, Y[i + 1]] ψz[z, Z[i]] +
       ϕ[i + 1, j - 1] ψy[y, Y[i + 1]] ψz[z, Z[i - 1]] +
       ϕ[i + 1, j] ψy[y, Y[i]] ψz[z, Z[i + 1]] +
       ϕ[i + 1, j + 1] ψy[y, Y[i + 1]] ψz[z, Z[i + 1]];
```

Then I noticed that your `BasisAssumY` shows that there's a simple relation between `X_[i_]` and `X_[i_+1_]`, so I think it may help if I introduce these relations as replacing rules rather than assumptions for `Integrate`:

```
deltarule = {a_[b_ + c_Integer] :> a[b] + c Symbol["Δ" <> ToLowerCase@ToString@a]}
```

You notebook for the 1D case and a close look for the definition of your `ψz` and `ψy` told me that I can even eliminate the `Y_[i]` if I shift the domain of `Integrate`:

```
shiftrule = {y -> y + Y[i], z -> z + Z[i]};
```

And finally, after some observation for the result given by the rules above, I think a simplification for those `Piecewise` function will help, too:

```
simplifyrule = 
  HoldPattern@Piecewise[a__] :> 
      Simplify[Piecewise[a], Δy > 0 && Δz > 0 && -Δy < y < Δy && -Δz < z < Δz];
```

OK, plug all this in:

```
exp = exp /. functionrule /. deltarule /. shiftrule /. simplifyrule
```

Now, the remaining assumptions are just:

```
BasisAssum = {Δy > 0, y ∈ Reals, Δz > 0, z ∈ Reals}
```

Finally, integrate with these assumptions:

```
(* Notice I've shifted the domain for integration *)
1/(Δz Δy)Integrate[exp, {y, -Δy, Δy}, {z, -Δz, Δz}, 
                   Assumptions -> BasisAssum] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

I use a 2GHz laptop.